# WordPress Пропала панель настройки внешнего вида

Tags: php, wordpress

Если тыкнуть на кнопку настроить:
[image: Если тыкнуть на кнопку настроить]
Вместо панели настройки внешнего вида просто путота:
[image: Вместо панели настройки внешнего вида просто путота]
Это дочерняя тема. Перед активацией можно было нажать "просмотр" и тогда все работало и показывалось, а сейчас вот так.

Что это может быть?

Comment: Плюс ко всему, если попытатся просмотреть родительскую тему, то получается тоже самое

Comment: Так же в консоли браузера я увидел такое: 
Warning:  array_intersect(): Argument #1 is not an array in /home/orgwp/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-customize-widgets.php on line 1343

Warning:  array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /home/orgwp/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-customize-widgets.php on line 1343.

Comment: Добавь в вопрос версию ВП, версию php и ссылку на тему, если тема из оф каталога.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тут все дело в том что это мультисайт. В мультисайте на вордпрессе есть еще одня категория юзеров - суперадмин, и только юзеры этой категории имеют привилегию управлять темами плагинами и некоторыми другими вещами. Если у вас возникли схожие проблемы и вы работаете с мультисайтом возможно проблема кроеться в привилегиях юзера.